# Error Message In Crystal Reports While Using SQL Queries

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have run a program in VS 2008 which is running just fine but the problem seems to be with VS 2010. Below mentioned is the error message that pops up when i try to run the program.

> ERROR MESSAGE
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have added .NET Framework 4.0 instead of .NET Framework 4.0 Client in the application properties.

I have added a reference CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Also I have mentioned the Namespace CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this in your app.config:**

```
< startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
< supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
< /startup>
```

Comment: @androidrill-If it solves your problem then mark it as an answer as it will be useful for others.

Comment: Sure i will Vishal, there is a bar of 5 mins by the website before I can mark it to be the right answer.